# Add Button into HTML Table with JavaScript without generator file

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I apologize in advance, English is not my native language.
I am working on a project that was delegated to me. I am working on a webpage, that is being generated by an XSLT file. I only have access to the source code of the generated page.

**What does it do:** The page shows a synopsis in form of a table. The left most column (lets call that one **A**) and the top most row (lets call it **B**) are the Header (?) segments (like in this table i found on [google](http://content.gcflearnfree.org/topics/96/pp03_sample_table.gif))
There are also Buttons in the top most row to sort the table.

**Now the problem:** There is a button to invert the table which activates the following code. This is where the problem is
I have this java code

```
// FAULTY FUNCTION BEGINNING                   
    function swap_table_horizontally_vertically() {

      //This is the code I already have
      // Deletes all sort buttons
      for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        try {
          var sort_buttons = document.getElementById('sort_buttons');
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err.message);
          continue;
        } finally {
          sort_buttons.parentNode.removeChild(sort_buttons);
        }
      }
      //End of the Code I made


      //This code was already in the file
      var old_table = document.getElementById('synopsis_table'),
      old_table_rows = old_table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
      cols = old_table_rows.length, rows = old_table_rows[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length,
      cell, next, temp_row, i = 0, new_table = document.createElement('table');


      while(i < rows) {
        cell = 0;
        temp_row = document.createElement('tr');
        if (i == 0) {
          while(cell < cols) {
            next = old_table_rows[cell++].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];

            temp_row.appendChild(next);
          }
          new_table.appendChild(temp_row);
          ++i;
        }
        else {
          while(cell < cols) {
            next = old_table_rows[cell++].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
            temp_row.appendChild(next);
          }
          new_table.appendChild(temp_row);
          ++i;
        }
      }


      old_table.parentNode.replaceChild(new_table, old_table);
      new_table.setAttribute("id", "synopsis_table");


    }
    // FAULTY FUNCTION END
```

Now what I need is a way to add the buttons again into the new table head (top most row) with a class and id attribute.

To summarize: I need to delete the buttons from the previous top most row (because the left column shouldn't have them) and add them again to the new top most row (the previous left column).